# Right clicking on plot to zoom in Bokeh

Tags: python, plot, visualization, bokeh

I recently started using Bokeh. Overall I am very satisfied. One thing I find annoying though is that it seems I can only play with the left mouse button and need to manually switch tools everytime I want to pan/zoom/etc... It would be great if I could pan with left mouse buttom and zoom in with right mouse button. Is there a way to automatically 'switch' to zoom tool whenever right mouse button held, and switch back when left mouse button held?

Thanks!

Comment: You can pan with the left and zoom with the mouse scroll wheel. At least in the only plot I had available here for a quick test (Bokeh 0.12.7), once you select the wheel zoom it stays active until you click it again.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida thats good, but I would like to select the region of zoom by holding down the right mouse button.

Comment: There is [a ticket open](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/5651) to use the keyboard to switch tools and interact with them, but it hasn't seen any movement.